# Collision Detection in XNA 4.0 Inaccurate

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision-detection

I'm having some trouble with 2D collision detection in an asteroids game I'm trying to make using XNA when rotating sprites.  The collision keeps happening before the bullet hits the asteroid (from every side it seems) and is also inaccurate when the ship crashes into an asteroid.  I use a matrix to rotate the bullet shot by the ship and then a matrix for an asteroid, and am using a per pixel collision detection sample on one of the Xbox Indie Game forums.

```
public static bool IntersectPixels(Matrix transformA, int widthA, int heightA, Color[] dataA, Matrix transformB, 
        int widthB, int heightB, Color[] dataB, float rotationA)
    {
        Matrix transformAToB = transformA * Matrix.Invert(transformB);

        Vector2 stepX = Vector2.TransformNormal(Vector2.UnitX, transformAToB);
        Vector2 stepY = Vector2.TransformNormal(Vector2.UnitY, transformAToB);

        Vector2 yPosInB = Vector2.Transform(Vector2.Zero, transformAToB);

        // For each row of pixels in A
        for (int yA = 0; yA < heightA; yA++)
        {
            // Start at the beginning of the row
            Vector2 posInB = yPosInB;

            // For each pixel in this row
            for (int xA = 0; xA < widthA; xA++)
            {
                // Round to the nearest pixel
                int xB = (int)Math.Round(posInB.X);
                int yB = (int)Math.Round(posInB.Y);

                // If the pixel lies within the bounds of B
                if (0 <= xB && xB < widthB &&
                    0 <= yB && yB < heightB)
                {
                    // Get the colors of the overlapping pixels
                    Color colorA = dataA[xA + yA * widthA];
                    Color colorB = dataB[xB + yB * widthB]

                    if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // Move to the next pixel in the row
                posInB += stepX;
            }
            // Move to the next row
            yPosInB += stepY;
        }
        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }
```

and here are my matrices for the bullet...Origin and Position are Vector2 Properties of the bullet

```
        private void UpdateTransform()
    {
        Transform =
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Origin, 0.0f)) *
                Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Rotation)) *
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Position, 0.0f));
    }
```

and the asteroid...

```
        private void UpdateTransform()
    {
        Transform =
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Origin, 0.0f)) *
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Position, 0.0f));
    }
```

I'm new to programming and I've spent the last couple days trying to figure out why the collision detection is inaccurate.  I thought that the matrices and possibly the per pixel collision detection method could be causing the problem, but am not sure what is wrong.  Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Comment: @AgentFire I don't think there's a need for definition. OP did say `The collision keeps happening before the bullet hits the asteroid (from every side it seems)` after all, which is inaccurate enough for me.

Comment: @Nolonar well, how much before?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, its probably about 15 pixels before....its kind of hard to tell, but definitely a noticeable amount to where someone playing the game would get frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

The pixel detection doesnt appear to account for the rotation of either object in the collision. You should investigate Axis Aligned Bounding Boxes (AABB) a little more. An orientated bounding box would rotate its collision intersects at the same degree of rotation as the rotation of the object, and works better in your case.

Take a look at this post on GameDev which has sample code that will take you further:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/is-there-a-good-way-to-get-pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in-xna